# How to read paths of more than 2000 files on dropbox?

Tags: python, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am trying to read the paths to all files from a remote (not local) dropbox folder using the dropbox api for python installed through anaconda. There are over 50,000 files on this folder including some in subfolders. I am getting files from subfolders. However, the total results returned seems to be capped at 2001. How can I return the paths for all 50,000 files?

```
dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(access)
results = dbx.files_list_folder(dbx_path_check, recursive=True)
dbx_files = list(i.path_display for i in results.entries)

print(len(dbx_files))
```

> 2001

Comment: Have you tried setting a `limit`? The [documentation](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moduledoc.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.files_list_folder) doesn't specify what the default limit is, but it seems possible to override.

Comment: This is a standard limit on many Dropbox API calls, you can find more by paginating through results, check out the docs for this function here: https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moduledoc.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.files_list_folder_continue

Comment: @JakeMorris setting a higher limit than 2000 returns an error.

Comment: @DanielleM. I only get an additional 2000 files back using continue. How do I tell it to stop paginating when all files have been found? Is there an example?

Comment: Read [this section of the documentation](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moduledoc.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.files_list_folder). It explains how to use the `ListFolderResult.has_more` field as an indicator that you should call `files_list_folder_continue()` to keep paginating through.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it's different in Drop box Api. Did you try something like this ?

```
 import os
 dbx_files = []
 for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(your_directory):
     dbx_files.append(os.path.join(root,filename))
 print(len(dbx_files))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This would work on a local folder but this is a remote dropbox folder. I have edited the question to reflect this.

Answer (score -1):

```
#Connect to the SQL database
import pyodbc 
import os
import json
import glob
from pathlib import Path 
import datetime as dt 
import string
import dropbox

#Connect to the DB
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};Server=atabase=;Trusted_Connection=yes;') 
print("Connection established")
cnxn.timeout = 60
cnxn.autocommit = True
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
dbx = dropbox.Dropbox("")
result = dbx.files_list_folder("", recursive=True, include_deleted=False, include_media_info=False)

def process_entries(entries):
    for entry in entries:
        if isinstance(entry, dropbox.files.FileMetadata):
            #print(entry.name)
            md, res = dbx.files_download(entry.path_lower)
            json_obj = json.loads(res.content)
            al_data = json.dumps(json_obj)
            .
            .
            .
            
            #Insert values into the DB         
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO dbo.audiolink_table_1 (...) 
process_entries(result.entries)
 
# Check if there are more files in the folder
while result.has_more: 
    result = dbx.files_list_folder_continue(result.cursor)
    process_entries(result.entries)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Explaining the underlying logic is more important than just giving the code. It helps the author and other readers fix this and similar issues themselves while giving them the clues to the knowledge they need to expand their programming skills.